# How to read out of a yml map<string, Map<string, string>> structure with cfg4j?

Tags: java, yaml

I have the following yml file

```
test-files:
  testSets:
    smoke:
      - "a" : "b"

    video:
      - "c" : "d"
```

I am trying to read this out using cfg4j but I don't seem to get the interface right.
What I want to get is a map with all the testSets with all the data for that set inside it.

So e.g. if I have the following map construction:

```
map<String, Map<String, String>>
```

I want to have in the first string the value smoke, in the second one a and the last one b etc.

The interface that I already tried to us for this is:

```
interface TestSets{
 Map<String, Map<String, String>> testSets;
}
```

But this doesn't work.
Has someone any idea about how to read this out using the cfg4j lib?

Answer (score 0):

CFG4J uses [type-parser](https://github.com/drapostolos/type-parser/wiki/#supported-arraycollectionmap-types) for deserialization. Non-nested maps can be expressed as strings:
Example here:

- [java](https://github.com/cfg4j/cfg4j-sample-apps/blob/master/classpath-bind/src/main/java/org/cfg4j/sample/ReksioConfig.java#L19)
- [yaml](https://github.com/cfg4j/cfg4j-sample-apps/blob/master/classpath-bind/src/main/resources/application.yaml#L29)

Unfortunately, nested Maps are currently not supported in CFG4J ([issue](https://github.com/cfg4j/cfg4j/pull/178)).